# Auto-Renewable subscription renewal and cancellation detection and receipt refresh

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, auto-renewable

I've implemented a local receipt validation routine to extract the expiration date of subscriptions and it is working correctly. But I'm having hard time finding out when exactly the receipt gets updated automatically and when should I force a refresh.

I have a couple of question regarding the matter

1) Does SKPaymentQueue.default() ever gets updated externally by Apple? Or it only gets updated when a transaction is triggered on the device locally?

2) Can we be certain that after a purchase of an auto-renewable subscription product, receipt gets updated automatically? Should I update the receipt with a SKReceiptRefreshRequest() after the purchase has been verified within 

    `paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updated Transactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])`

Or after a purchase completes can I directly go and read from the receipt the new expiration date without calling SKReceiptRefreshRequest()?

Please note that I am asking about refreshing the receipt from Apple's servers and not validating or reading expiration date from it.

3) If user cancels the subscription or the payment method fails at the renewal date, does Apple automatically updates the apps receipt or should I refresh the receipt with a SKReceiptRefreshRequest() request each time app starts in order to detect subscription cancellations?

4) When an auto-renewable subscription gets renewed successfully, does Apple automatically updates the apps receipt or should I refresh the receipt with a SKReceiptRefreshRequest() request each time app starts to get the new receipt in order to get the new expiration date when an renewal occurs?

5) Does refreshing the receipt with a SKReceiptRefreshRequest() request asks the user for their App Store credentials every time?

As you can see my main confusion is around when it is needed to force a ReceiptRefresh and when can I rely on the SKPaymentQueue or StoreKit to update it automatically.

Any insight would be welcome.